# Can google script be used to make the list broadcast

Tags: google-apps-script

Can google script be used to make the list broadcast api for you tube and the stream and basically can you make the broadcast samples using scripts i have made the other samples but it is unclear if scripts can be used to the broadcast. Also it appears that depending on the manor of which i access the scripts app I get different options. For instance if i access the the scripts app using google drive I can share and other stuff that is not available if i access the google drive though api and the regular free account. I wonder if there is a better way to access to get all the services? I think before the scripts service would not work for the broadcast. however it appears it has been updated is that because i have a credit card on file now? i notice i have more options now than before in scripts.

Comment: This question is too broad to answer in the Stack Overflow format. Please edit it to be more specific. (You've asked five questions in one.)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer yes you can make broadcast api from you tube ver (3) on google scripts as long as you have a credit card on file. That's cool google deserves to get paid. With out your card key elements are missing in scripts and everyplace else. Makeing it difficult if not impossible for hacks like me to get the api back on the internet. But with a credit card on file wow two clicks and its done no coding nada just change out the public api credential. I just wish this would have been told to me months ago. and please everyone forget about java, go, java-script and everything else if you want a web-service or web app from youtube api. Use in this order Python .php  google scripts.  But i did learn how to become a expert developer its called master card. this is my experience only and i still think its a great thing but if your not a genius use your card you will feel like one.